# How to make winmerge show only missing lines between two files?

Tags: winmerge

How would I only show 'missing lines' between two files? I am trying to do a file system directory comparison (a directory list) - and in the 2nd file system there are time/date stamp differences which I don't care about - but are showing up as 'line differences'. I only want to show 'missing lines' (i.e., where files are not present on the 1st or 2nd file system).

I'd only like to show missing lines in either file directory listing (both text files).

How would I do that?

Comment: Look through Options, General, and see if ignoring blank lines help.  V2.16.24.0 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

I suggest in *Edit > Options > Compare > Folder* to set the "Compare method"
to "Size".

This is in order to ignore time-stamps and show only different-sized files.

You should also in the View menu to
disable "Show identical Items".

I think that as far as you can refine the search.

This will show files that are larger, not only smaller.
You may right-click on any column header and select "Customize Columns..."
and add the columns of "Left Size" and "Right Size", to be able to select
only smaller files.